# Android service with locationListener callbacks

Tags: android, service, geolocation, locationlistener

I have an android application. Based on the current geo location of user, I want to fetch some remote data in background and store it. My implementation is:

At specific interval a alarm fires up my service. Service uses an anonymous class to query current location and registers a locationListener callback. On call of onLocationChanged() I initiate the remote data fetch from server.

However once my service is done registering the location listener using anonymos class, it returns as expected; as it doesn't wait for callback to happen before finishing. Since callback takes some time and makes a call when service has already returned, it throws an error saying:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Handler{43e82510} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
```

Which is quite understandable. One quick workaround for me now is that I can use getLastKnownLocation from locationManager as that doesn't respond back by callback; but what if I do want the latest location right now, in a service and not activity? How can I wait for callback to happen and stop my service from returning.

Also, at what point does lastKnownlocation gets updated? Everytime GPS registers a new location; does it update it? What I want to know is that if it's not latest can it still be closed to latest? As I didn't see an option in android emulator to configure the time period between subsequent updates.

Any help is much appreciated.
Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but what if I do want the latest location right now, in a service and not activity?

Sorry, but that is not possible, in either a service or an activity. For example, if the GPS radio is off, and you are requesting location data from GPS, it will take tens of seconds just to get a fix, and that's if you are lucky. It might not get a fix at all.

> How can I wait for callback to happen and stop my service from returning.

You don't. You do what you said you would do:

> use getLastKnownLocation from locationManager as that doesn't respond back by callback

So, have your `Service` (which is hopefully an `IntentService`) check to see if `getLastKnownLocation()` happens to have a value. If it does, use it. Otherwise, `registerLocationUpdates()` using a `PendingIntent` that will pass control back to your `IntentService`. When you get *that* `Intent`, use the location and unregister for updates (assuming the alarm period is nice and long, like, say, once an hour).

Things get tricky if your alarm is a _WAKEUP alarm. You will then need to hold a `WakeLock`, so the device does not fall back asleep while you are trying to get a GPS fix. However, you need to release that `WakeLock` sometime, and if we cannot get a GPS fix...ummm...well, that's the tricky part. Trying to figure out a nice clean way of handling this, and implementing it as a reusable component (e.g., `LocationAlarmService`), is one of 18,000 items on my to-do list.

> Also, at what point does lastKnownlocation gets updated? Everytime GPS registers a new location; does it > update it?

AFAIK, yes.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark, that did clear up lot of things for me. At least it re-instate the belief that I am not the only one who cannot get this right. :)

Comment: Let me know when you get through the todo list. Also, the Google Play services location service might be helpful to acquire location.