# Running location update in a separate thread in android service

Tags: android, service, location, runnable

I am bit confused in deciding the way i should implemnt my background service tasks. Following is my service looks like.

Android service(Have two tasks to do in background)

1. Register for locationListener and when new location received , process it for deciding best location or not.
2. Poll to a server every 10 mins to check if any server side changes to the remote database.

Now I don't want these two tasks fight for timing and resources. So I am planning to run these two simultaneously. For Polling to server I am using repeated timerTask but for LocationListener what should I use?

Is it ok to use a java runnable to process the new location with some logic and update the location to server? If my idea is ok please provide some sample code to show how can I execute the location updates in a new thread.

If you think any problem in my current idea please suggest some new for my requirements.

Answer (score 1):

I see nothing, that suggest you can't register a LocationListener that runs in your service, in the documentation: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html

This is a similar question with an answer, you should read it:
[Android service with locationListener callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743474/android-service-with-locationlistener-callbacks)

"Now I don't want these two tasks fight for timing and resources. So I am planning to run these two simultaneously."
^ vague statement followed by a seemingly counter-intuitive plan. If you could be specific about what you mean by "timing" and "resources" then you might get some useful feedback on that one.

Short answer:
Yes. Register a LocationListener, it will get called when a Location update is available. It's a LISTENER in that it gets called when its needed by whatever you register it to - you don't need to call it yourself. Best practice is to not have a repeat on TimerTask, instead use one-shots that get reset by the code that gets called each tick.

As for free code, perhaps you should hire someone to do the hard work for you? It'll create another job in the Android community and mitigate the risks involved in you attempting something you're not well versed in. Otherwise, get your hands dirty and try implementing it the way you think it'll best work, come back to Stack Overflow if/when you encounter a specific problem.

Comment: straya : thanks for your reply. But from you answer it  seems you are thinking the Task and location update task are same. Currently I am not using the TimerTask for locations. But the timer task is used to get some database updates from remote webserver. May be the while running the timerTask my location listener is called. That's why I was thinking to implement the thread. If you can comment on my new clarification.. it will be helpful for me...

Comment: No I don't think they are the same. If you think that's what I think based on what I've written, something is wrong on your end. Re-read what I said very carefully. Register the Listener, let it do its thing. Setup the TimerTask, let it do its thing. What do you care if they run "at the same time" (makes me think you're holding back on important information...)